# Stripe + Parse - Can't figure out Javascript promises

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, stripe-payments

This will be an easy javascript answer for someone that knows, but I'm not that great with javascript.

I'm using Stripe + Parse. In this function I need to:
1. Create a Customer
2. Charge that Customer

I'm having a problem with the promise syntax.

I need to `success` only when both Stripe calls return success. However, I need to call `error` when either returns an error. I don't know where to put these given this chained syntax.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("chargeToken",function(request,response)
{

    Stripe.Customers.create({

      card: request.params.card,
      description: request.params.description

    }).then(function(customer) {

      return Stripe.Charges.create({

        amount: request.params.amount,
        currency: request.params.currency,
        customer: customer.id,

        success:function(results)
            {
                response.success(results);
            },
        error:function(error)
            {
                response.error("Error:" +error); 
            }

      });
    });
});
```

This code is taken from the examples on Stripe's site, however, there wasn't an example sample for what I needed and this is the best I came up with.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  Are you saying that you want to use the result from `Stripe.Charges.create()`?  If `Stripe.Charges.create()` returns an error, that error will go up the chain because you're returning a fresh promise.  Or are you saying you want success/error on the whole thing?

Comment: @Brad The problem as is is that I'm getting an error of: `Error: success/error was not called` on return of the `Parse.Cloud` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write your success and error handling code as the last handler in the chain. For e.g.:

```
Stripe.Customers.create({
  card: request.params.card,
  description: request.params.description
}).then(function(customer) {
  return Stripe.Charges.create({
    amount: request.params.amount,
    currency: request.params.currency,
    customer customer.id
  });
}).done(function(results) {
  response.success(results);
}, function(err) {
  response.error('Error:' + err);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error of: `Error: success/error was not called` on return of the `Parse.Cloud` function on this implementation as well. This is the same error as the original code.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the Parse API but from a quick search it looks like Parse cloud functions have hard [timeout limits](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-resource) for async requests. Maybe the Stripe calls are taking longer than what Parse allows (which seems to be 15 seconds at this point)?